# Service Remoting V2 service- Client connectivity outside the cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

How to access a "Service Remoting V2" Service outside Service Fabric Cluster?

Answer (score 1):

SF Remoting is intended to work within the cluster. You can use [WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-wcf) communication, combined with a `ServicePartitionResolver` configured with your cluster location as a workaround.

Using WCF will allow any client technology that understands SOAP or REST to connect to your service.

[Here's](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.WcfCalc) a sample implementation for a WCF service in ASF. 
[This](http://blogs.recneps.net/post/Service-Fabric-Resolving-External-Service-Address) blog post describes how to use the resolver.